# how we apply xor in php array

Tags: php, arrays, xor

**hot deck imputation algoritm:** 
for each object that contains missing values the most similar object (according to some distance function) is found, and the missing values are imputed from that object
if the most similar record also contains missing values for the same feature then it is discarded and another closest object is found
the procedure is repeated until all the missing values are imputed 
when no similar object is found, the closest object with the minimum number of missing values is chosen to impute the missing values 
**bellow the table contain missing values**

[image]

the missing value fill bellow the table using xor operation

[image]

if the 1st object contain null value the we compare this object to all other rows and count distance and found shortest distance then put the missing values

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: It's completely, unclear, how you expect to apply an XOR to the elements of this arrays. It's also unclear what you mean by "*compare null value array to all other array*" here.